# can you use python random module inside django models to create unique id

Tags: python, django, random, model

i'm building an invoicing web app, so I want to be able to create a unique id of every invoice but also I want to control how the id looks eg "",BU236718N

```
from random import randint, choice
from django.db import models

def myID():
    my_id = "BU" + randint(1,100000) + choice("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    return(my_id)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.CharField(myID)

   def __str__(self):
        return (self.invoice_number)
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

The birthday paradox says that when picking items with repetition from a set of `n` items, you can expect a collision after roughly `sqrt(n)` picks.  You have 2,600,000 items, so you can expect a collision after about 1600 picks.

Yes, this trick can work, but you need to use strings much longer than this.  It is common to use UUIDs, or something derived from a UUID, as a unique global identifier.  These are 128 bits.